# firewall on server preventing access by multiple computers on same NAT'ed ip

Tags: centos, virtualhost, vps

I am encountering a strange problem with my VPS provider and wondered if anyone here with firewall / sysadmin experience had seen anything like this.

Has anyone seen a situation where a firewall or similar program is configured to cause a slowdown to traffic when it sees tcp requests coming from multiple computers on the same ip address?

```
              |
              |      +---+
              |     -+   |
+----+        | ---/ +---+
|    |        +/    client 1
+----+--------\
server        |-\
              |  --\ +---+
              |     -+   |
              |      +---+
            NAT     client 2
```

Here's a little graphic of the scenario.  The server first sees a request from either client 1 or 2 (doesn't matter the order) and then a request 10 seconds later from the other computer gets delayed until it timeouts.  Requests from the first computer continue without abatement.

I've done TCP dumps to see what could be happening, but as far as I can tell, whatever is causing the slowdown is in the tcp packet or below - it's not any application-level information.  I can send plain TCP packets without application information and this uniformly happens.  It's just so weird, and whenever I search out this problem it only brings information on configuring the NAT.  But it's not the NAT that's at issue - this actually occurs no matter where I am, as long as it is this scenario.

You can actually see this for yourself by accessing my server, zenia.co, from your computer, and then try to access it immediately after from a different computer on your same network, or from a mobile phone using that network for wifi.  as long as the server sees the same ip but different tcp /ip info (maybe different window sizes or TTL's or something, it's boggling!

This is particularly worrying because if two users try to access the server from the same ip (like two users on desktops from a single business) it will allow one but mysteriously block the other, and then I've maybe just lost a user.

To emphasize - I am just interested if this is something that is standard practice on certain server types - that's why I am asking among you network engineers / sysadmins.  I'm not trying to fix something broken.

Technical details:
The box is a virtual CentOS server.
Whether I turn the box firewall on or off, this happens.
Whatever application I hit on the box (Tomcat, Lighttpd, telnet), this happens.

*Follow up, 6/9/2016*: This was the case at a lower-quality VPS provider.  I think it was just a bungled firewall config on their side.

Comment: Please add some logging

Comment: I tried accessing that domain from two computers on the same LAN. I saw no problems. You need to provide a packet capture of the traffic from the WAN interface of the NAT before it will be possible to debug the issue any further. Packet captures from each client and the server may also be useful, if you run the packet captures on the different hosts simultaneously.